# How to fix JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net

the error that occurred usually happen if I don't include:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

In the code or I put the jquery before I put script `src`. The problem is I did not do anything wrong with it yet still get the error.

Is there anything that I might be overlooked in order to fix the error?

Comment: You must include jQuery before any related code.

Comment: that's the problem I currently experienced. already include the jquery reference but the same error keep popup

Comment: 1.You have to put jquery base/core library before any other library/code-snippet. 2.sometime it happens when two different libraries got conflicted [one of them using older version like `jQuery` and some one want new version with `$`].3 sometime it happens when other libraries not putted in correct manner, means to say that may any library need to put first but you putted it after other-one

Comment: This question would be greatly improved by the inclusion of a [mcve]. It would also benefit from the exact text of the error message that appears in the console including the location of where it is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must include jquery before any script which uses jquery.**

**Why '$' is undefined?**

**Case: 1**
Because jQuery is a javascript library(collection of class and methods). When it is used on a web page it creates its own object. $ holds the reference of that object.
Later at any point of time we can use $ to use any jQuery method.
e.g $.each(),$.get()...etc

So before use of jQuery method in your code or any other js library in code which uses jQuery must include after jQuery.

**Case: 2**
You should check into the browser's console (to reach, press F12 then go into console tab). There might be chance that your code before jQuery inclusion has some error.

Comment: So what's your case in the above cases?

Answer (score 0):

Every code which uses jquery, should be placed after jquery script tag.
I don't know how your code lines are aligned, so I'll give you the example of the wrong cases.

## Wrong cases:

### #1

```
<head>
  <script> $... </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

### #2

```
<head>
  <script> $... </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

### #3

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script> $... </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

$... also indicates jquery dependent libraries such as jquery.ui.